# Bootstrap modal does not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap framework and trying to display a modal. I have seen the exact question on StackOverflow but still could not make it work.

Here is the part where I try to implement the modal popup:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1">
  <h3>Appify</h3>
  <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is my full **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
      <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
      <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1140x350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Featured Work</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1">
      <h3>Appify</h3>
      <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
      <h3>Appify</h3>
      <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
      <h3>Appify</h3>
      <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
      <h3>Appify</h3>
      <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Favorite App Page</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
                This was my first project in this class. I learned a lot about HTML and CSS.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and here you can see my file structure:

[image]

I expect to see a modal when I click at the picture under **Featured Work** title, but it does not show up. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Try loading jQuery before Bootstrap JS maybe?

Comment: jQuery should be called before the bootstrap js.

Comment: Place the jquery 3.2 file before bootstrap.min.js

Comment: @Roberrrt thanks, I did not think about looking at the console before but now when I look at it, I see the following error message: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:11". Let me try to fix that and then I will edit the question here.

Comment: Placing jquery file before bootstrap worked. It looks like a stupid mistake since I have just started web development. Thanks a lot to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call jquery before bootstrap js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Just a quick question: how do I know that I need to call jquery before bootstrap? I could not see any warning about that in documentation

Comment: Simple, Bootstrap JS has jQuery as a dependency. Dependencies should be loaded BEFORE

Comment: Ok it is clear now thanks again. I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Simple: Bootstrap JS needs jQuery. If it works don't forget to mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working demo for you:

**Jquery should be placed before Bootstrap.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
          <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
          <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1140x350">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Featured Work</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Favorite App Page</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
                    This was my first project in this class. I learned a lot about HTML and CSS.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Already answered before

Comment: Sure, somebody would have while I was coding / answering. Didn't saw.